# how to access webcam video using react

Tags: reactjs

I tried to stream my webcam video using react. The browser got rendering of the video tag with specified height and weight. Yet My webcam video is not playing? What mistake have I done? I m new to react.

```
import React from 'react'
import reactDom from 'react-dom'
import {useState, useEffect,useRef} from 'react'

function MyVideo() {
    let Video=document.getElementsByClassName('video')
    useEffect(()=>{
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio:true,
            video:true
        }).then (stream=>{
            Video.srcObject=stream;
        })
    },[])
    return (
        <div>
        <video width='750' height='500'autoplay controls className='video'>
        </video>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MyVideo
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to `query` `video` node inside `useEffect`. [Here is the complete example](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-panka-uf9ng?file=/src/App.js).